# href adds unwanted '.pdf' to path provided

Tags: hyperref, links

I have following code in my tex file.

```
\\href{DEListComparison/inputFilesForGENE_E/}{link caption} \\
```

The link in the output pdf file turn out to be *DEListComparison/inputFilesForGENE_E/.pdf*. I got unnecessary .pdf in the link. Is this a bug or I did something stupid? How can it be resolved ?

Comment: Is `DEListComparison/inputFilesForGENE_E/` a complete URL string? If so, try prefixing `http://` to the string. If it's something else, please advise. (It would appear that `hyperref` thinks it's a shortcut to a file, with extension `.pdf`, located somewhere on your computer.)

Comment: it is a relative url of a directory which is in same root directory as the output pdf file (generated by latex).

Answer (score 3):

There is an ambiguity in `\href` between a file link and an incomplete relative URL without protocol. Package `hyperref` chooses the former.

The following example provides macro `\hrefurl` that directly chooses the URL link type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\hrefurl}{\hyper@normalise\hrefurl@}
\providecommand*{\hrefurl@}[2]{\hyper@linkurl{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hrefurl{DEListComparison/inputFilesForGENE_E/}{link caption}
\end{document}
```

Now the PDF file contains an URI action for the link:

```
/A <<
  /Type /Action
  /S /URI
  /URI(DEListComparison/inputFilesForGENE_E/)
>>
```